# I'm working on a MongoDB schema design. There is a confusion

Tags: mongodb, database-design, schema

I am currently working on MongoDB schema. But there's a bit of confusion.
Description of the portion of the schema.

**USER**

```
user {
 _id : ObjectId('asdasdadsadasdad'),
birth : "1987.06.11",
gender : "men",
user_id : "namename"
}
```

**Marketing**

```
marketing {
  ????
  I need gender and birthday information in db.marking.
}
```

What should I do?

I'm sorry about the grammar.
I'm using it as a translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend embedding the user details inside the marketing schema as these fields, the user is rarely going to change so

```
 marketing {
    user: {
       _id: ObjectId('asdasdadsadasdad')
       gender: "men",
       birth : "1987.06.11"
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank you but I have another question. This is a fixed schema, and if it changes, can I use it as it is?

Comment: yes if any changes made in the user, it is not going to affect this schema here because we are interested in only three fields.

Comment: Right. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you.